# GoogleNews date range

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-news

I am trying to build a tool to pull news articles mentioning a key word in the text body but cannot get the date range to work.

Ideally I only want to view articles in the past 24 hours so I am using this:

```py
googlenews=GoogleNews(period='1d')
```

However in my DataFrame results I am getting fields in the date column like "3 weeks ago", "1 month ago" etc

perhaps a solution would be to specify where the date is <today() and then drop the lines where the text contains "week", "weeks", "month", "months" etc.

```
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
from newspaper import Article
import pandas as pd

search_term = "Binoculars"

googlenews=GoogleNews(period='1d')
googlenews=GoogleNews(lang='en', region='US')
googlenews.search(search_term)

results = []

final_results = []

for page in range(1,5):
 googlenews.getpage(page) 
 results.extend(googlenews.result())

for item in results: 
 if (item not in final_results and (search_term in item["desc"])):
     final_results.append(item)
else:
    pass

df=pd.DataFrame(results)
df
```

Comment: _"ideally i only want to view articles in the past 24 hours so i am using this:"_ - you are overwriting that variable directly in the next line. You should pass all three parameters at the same time.

Comment: I think you mean `googlenews=GoogleNews(lang='en', region='US', period='1d')`

Comment: thank you both - seems very logical - i didn't actually realise my lang/region was overwriting the period.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot test this just yet as i'm getting hit with "HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests" d'oh!!!

Comment: hmm.. my reply didnt post yesterday - the solution above did not work and i am still receiving YTD results. 

i wonder if i can set a parameter on the datetime column to only return rows where the datestring is equal to yesterday's date?